# Curved Dome shaped wood

Tags: wood

I am trying to build a wood structure with the domes at top. I need some suggestion on how to build the domes at the top. Can you please let me know how they are built ? They look curved. How can I curve wood like that ? Please see the below picture there are three domes.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wood can take any form: it's not inherently flat, we just cut it into shapes with flat sides because that tends to be useful. But bowl turners, for example, often start with a chunk of a log and cut a curved bowl from the log without first cutting the wood flat.

There are three ways that you can end up with curved wood:

- It can grow that way.
- It can be cut into the curve that you want.
- It can be cut into flat pieces and then bent.

A tree is unlikely to grow into the dome shape that you want, so that leaves you with cutting and bending as options. It's hard to tell what the scale of the pictured piece is; if it's small, like something you can hold in your hands, then the domes were likely carved along with the many other carved features. Or, the individual facets may have been cut separately and glued up. If it's large, like a bed, then perhaps the facets were bent, cut to shape, and then glued together to form the dome.

Comment: I have flat wood.  I have seen some videos on youtube. One technique is Kerf bending. Are there any other techniques like that ?

Comment: Kerf bending is one way. Steam bending and curved lamination are others. As indicated, how you do it depends a lot on the size of the thing you're making.

Comment: There is also hot pipe bending, if your stock is thin enough.